# Capybara screenshot_and_open_image save whole page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have issue with `screenshot_and_open_image` from `gem capybara-screenshot`

i have large page witch need to be scrolled till the end

i have tried to set resolution for screenshot,doesn't help

How to save whole page not only visible part?

Comment: try to use the `gem "launchy"` instead `capybara-screenshot`

Comment: Show the code you have tried, and tell us what driver you are using with Capybara